AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_list'
From excel I'm importing the following table as dataframe in pandas:

to import those I'm using the following code:
f_1=df.iloc[indice, df.columns.get_loc('col1')]
f_2=df.iloc[indice, df.columns.get_loc('col2')]
f_3=df.iloc[indice, df.columns.get_loc('col3')]

I want to create strings based on the "row" in the first column, so something like
string1=ae1
string2=bf2
string3=cg3
string4=d

If I try to convert the f_1 f_2 and f_3 in a list using .to_list() it gives me this error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_list'

using a print('f_1', f_1) and so on for the other two variables I see


Could you add what the expected values of f_1, f_2, and f_3 are? I am pretty sure they are a, e, and 1 respectively now

added a picture of what I see when I print f_1 and so on

I believe that f_1 is holding a string 'a\nb\nc\nd'. what is your indice value? what do you get for df.to_dict()?

You can use .apply() metod directly to df to get string from each row like this:
df.iloc[indice, df.columns.isin(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis = 1)

